# since and until arguments cause an error in R

Tags: r, search, twitter

```
donald_tweets <- searchTwitter("Donald + Trump Republicans exclude:retweets", 
                               n=50, lang = "en", since = "2016-03-16", until = "2016-03-17")
donald_tweets
```

But this gives me error.

```
Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit
```

50 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0
and somewhere I have seen that this is the problem with since and until that these since and until search for fewer days. As it is 2018 not 2016. But what can I do in this regard? Please help! This is the project in R.

Comment: What package does `searchTwitter` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Twitter Search Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) contains two useful pieces of information.

It says that `until`:

> Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week.

It also shows that there is no `since` parameter. It is `since_id`:

> Returns results with an ID greater than (that is, more recent than) the specified ID. There are limits to the number of Tweets which can be accessed through the API. If the limit of Tweets has occured since the since_id, the since_id will be forced to the oldest ID available.

So there are the two errors in your code.  You cannot search for anything older than a week. If you want to use a "since" parameter, you have to give it an ID, not a date.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me but I have taken these two arguments from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364908/how-to-extract-tweets-between-a-certain-time-period-in-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa                                                             and since is availabe in twitteR package.

Comment: and what-if I want to have the data for 2016?

Comment: Twitter doesn't let normal users access historic data in search.  As mentioned in the the [twitteR documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf)  "there are pagination restrictions as well as other limits on what can be searched,"

Comment: I am a needy student. I can't afford the Twitter's premium access to API to get the historical tweets. MyUniversity is also not funding me in my research. Kindly help me in this regard. That will be very helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: #Terence Sir, I have even searched for tweets fromTweetDeck (https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/) but found no way how to download them or to just have text. I manually copy pasted them but it was really hectic.

Comment: done the same above procedure with this one (https://twitter.com/search-advanced) too but can't have much of it and junk is also included

Comment: @Mahnoor Sadly, there is no way around this. Twitter lets you use their website for historical research, but does not allow API access to it.